# Inserting a new element in a Java Map or Updating and existing element by its key

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

**The business request** is that I construct a `List<ResponsePOJO>` from a `List<RequestPOJO>`. This seems simple enough.
The request actually needs some(*more*) processing, meaning that I need to save a couple of parameters, then for every element do a request to a CassandraMicroservice that returns a `List<CassandraPOJO>`. Every element of this `<List<CassandraPOJO>` has it's own `List<DataPOJO>` that needs to fall in a category represented by some specific characteristics in the `List<ResponsePOJO>`. Essentially for every element in the `List<RequestPOJO>` I am building a `List<List<DataPOJO>>` that needs to be dealt with. Unfortunately, everything is stuck as it is so **I cannot change the architecture**.
In short, **my problem is** that I am unable to find a simple `createOrUpdate` on `Map`. I tried to make an `updateOrCreate` of the type `BiFunction`. I think it should be enough to do something like a BiFunction, Map> that should look like (*pseudocode*):

```java
private BiFunction<ResponsePOJO, Map<Integer, ResponsePOJO>, Map<Integer, ResponsePOJO>> updateOrCreate(?*) {
        return (newValue, currentResult) -> {
            if (currentResult.contains(newValue)) 
                currentResult.updateParams(newValue);            
            else
                currentResult.put(newValue);
            return currentResult;
        };
    }
```

**?*** I noticed that the call to a BiFunction is parameterless, how does it know what type its parameters are? (*not my main question*, but I think one reason for my problem is the lack of truly understanding `BiFunction` together with `Map.compute`)
The (almost) complete code snippet is:

```java
// the POJOs, using lombok (anotations skipped)  
public class RequestPOJO {
    private Long id;
    private Long idEntity;
    private Long idInventory;
    // some are omitted for brevity
}  

@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ResponsePOJO {
    private Integer id;
    private Long noInventory;
    private String nameSpecies;
    private Double g1;
    private Double g2;
    private Double g3;
    // some are omitted for brevity

    public void updateParams(ResponsePOJO resp) {
        // only these fields need updating, because of business logic
        this.g1 += resp.getG1();
        this.g2 += resp.getG2();
        this.g3 += resp.getG3();
    }
}

public class CassandraPOJO {
    private Long id;
    private List<DataPOJO> detailsDataPojo;
    private Long noInventory;
    // some are omitted for brevity
}


public class DataPOJO {
    private Long idSpecies;
    private Long idQualityClass;
    private Double height;
    private Double diameter;
    private Double noCount;
    // some are omitted for brevity
}

// the business logic
public List<ResponsePOJO> compute(List<RequestPOJO> requestPojoList, List<SpeciesPOJO>speciesList) {
        List<ResponsePOJO> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RequestPOJO requestPojo : requestPojoList) {
            Long idEntity = requestPojo.getIdEntity();
            Long noInventory = requestPojo.getIdInventory(); // yes I know this is wrong, stick to the question

            List<CassandraPOJO> res = cassandraMicroservice.getByIdEntityFilteredByNoInventory(idEntity, noInventory);

            res.stream().forEach(dar -> {  
                Map<Long, List<DataPOJO>> listDataPojoBySpeciesId =
                        dar.getDetailsDataPojo().stream().collect(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(DataPOJO::getIdSpecies, Collectors.toList())
                        );
                responseList.addAll(
                    classifyDataPojo(listDataPojoBySpeciesId, speciesList, dar.getNoInventory()) 
                );
            });
        }

        Comparator<ResponsePOJO> compareResponsePojo = Comparator.comparing(ResponsePOJO::getNameSpecies);
        return responseList.stream()
                .sorted(compareResponsePojo).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }  

    private List<ResponsePOJO> classifyDataPojo(Map<Long, List<DataPOJO>> listDataPojoBySpeciesId, List<SpeciesPOJO> speciesList, Long noInventory) {
        Map<Integer, ResponsePOJO> result = new HashMap();
        for (Long speciesId : listDataPojoBySpeciesId.keySet()) {
            String nameSpecies = speciesList.stream().filter(s -> s.getIdSpecies() == speciesId).findFirst().get().getNameSpecies(); // it's guaranteed to be found
            for (DataPOJO dataP : listDataPojoBySpeciesId.get(speciesId)) {
                Double volumeUnit = getVolumeUnit(dataP);
                Double equivalenceCoefficient = getEquivalentClass(dataP, speciesList);
                CustomTypeEnum customType = getCustomType(speciesList, dataP.getDiameter, speciesId);
                resp = ResponsePOJO.builder()
                        .noInventory(noInventory)
                        .nameSpecies(nameSpecies)
                        .build();
                switch (customType) {
                    case G1:
                        resp.setG1(volumeUnit * equivalenceCoefficient * dataP.getNoCount());
                        break;
                    case G2:
                        resp.setG2(volumeUnit * equivalenceCoefficient * dataP.getNoCount());
                        break;                    
                    case G3:
                        resp.setG3(volumeUnit * equivalenceCoefficient * dataP.getNoCount());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            int diameter = ComputeUtil.getDiamenterClass(resp.getDiameter());
            // doesn't compile, it says Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: BiFunction<ResponsePOJO, Map<Integer, ResponsePOJO>, Map<Integer,ResponsePOJO>> Required: BiFunction<? super Integer,? super ResponsePOJO,? extends ResponsePOJO>             
            result.compute(diameter, updateOrCreate());
            // I have fiddled with reduce and merge but to no avail
            // result.values().stream().reduce(new ArrayList<>(), updateOrCreate(), combiningFunction());
            // result.merge(diameter, update())
        }
        return result.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I chose Map because I want it to be as fast as possible, this method `compute(...)` is called pretty often and I don't want to search through all the response list everytime I need something updated. I am reluctant to change the POJOs, especially the `CassandraPOJO` that has the `DataPOJO`.
As you can see this is a mixture of both classical `for` and java8 `stream`. I intend to change all the code according to java8 but it took me a considerable amount of time to write this (convoluted, hard-to-follow, easier-to-understand) code.
I am firmly convinced that there is an easier solution, but I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: Did you consider using `Map::computeIfAbsent` or `Map::computeIfPresent`?

Comment: Do you understand that a map has a key **and** a value? There is no sense in trying to call `put` with a single argument.

Comment: @y_ug I did look on both. The documentation says **computeIfAbsent**: "If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null" so it won't do a remmaping unless it is absent, it should update.  
**computeIfPresent**: "If the value for the specified key is present and non-null, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value." so if the element is not found it won't do anything, it should insert.

Comment: @Holger it is not a code snippet, but more like a pseudocode, it should just convey the idea of *putting an element*. I've added a clarification.

Comment: But it's impossible for a reader to guess what you are intending to do by such misleading code. It's not helpful that the question starts with this code fragment, whereas the actual `compute` call is buried under tons of entirely irrelevant code. Anyway, you got an answer. Why don't you respond to that?

Comment: @Holger I beg to differ. All that irrelevant code is meant to point that it's not a trivial job and also it helps paint the whole picture for clarity sake. Not all questions are answerable at a glance.     
I am testing right now, migrating some databases, instantiating, hold your horses. I will give an informed answer.

Comment: Your question is about updating the map. Nothing more. All the other stuff is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst that lengthy code, it looks to me you are simply looking for a `merge` operation such as:

```
result.merge(diameter, resp, (a, b) -> { 
    a.updateParams(b);
    return a;
});
return new ArrayList<>(result.values());
```

which can be abstracted out as

```
private BiFunction<ResponsePOJO, ResponsePOJO, ResponsePOJO> mergeResponse() {
    return (a, b) -> {
        a.updateParams(b);
        return a;
    };
}
```

and used further as

```
result.merge(diameter, resp, mergeResponse());
```

Comment: I only want to add that `result.merge(diameter, resp, mergeResponse())` is called in the innermost `for`